# Approaches to passing multiple data tables to a function using lapply in R

Tags: r, lapply

In general I often need to pass several data tables in turn to a function which performs some modification to the data table, and then have this modified table returned to the global environment.  As a basic example, melting a wide format timeseries, and also renaming one of the variables:

```
DT1 <- data.table("Country"=c("UK","France"),
                  "22.1.20"=c(30,32), "23.1.20"=c(32,34), "24.1.20"=c(42,44))

DT2  <- data.table("Country"=c("UK","France"),
                "22.1.20"=c(10,20), "23.1.20"=c(12,22), "24.1.20"=c(14,24))

DTList <- list(DT1, DT2) #list of wide format timeseries data tables with Country column and case counts 
                         #by country in numerous date columns

meltAndNameDT <- function(DT) {

  DT <- melt(DT, variable.name="Date", value.name="Count")  #reshape dataset
  setnames(DT,  old="Date", new="observationDate")          #rename variable
  return(DT)

}
```

It is simple enough to write functions and manually call them  with each dataset being passed explicitly, but this is verbose and inflexible, so I would like to be able to do it within lapply, using a list of the data tables I wish to modify.

Using lapply as in `lapply(DTList, meltAndNameDT)` returns a list of the modified data tables, but obviously does not assign them to their original names.  To do this needs (I think) some screwing around to re-assign them sequentially to the objects in DTList, which is made more difficult since those objects are not named.  I also wonder if this would be efficient in terms of memory use and time processing.

The simplest alternative seems to be to pass a vector of the data table names held as strings, and have the function modify the data tables in the global environment, i.e.:

```
DTList <- c("DT1", "DT2")

meltAndNameDT <- function(DT) {

  assign(DT, melt(get(DT), variable.name="Date", value.name="Count"),envir=globalenv())  #reshape dataset
  setnames(get(DT), old="Date", new="observationDate")                                   #rename variable

}

lapply(DTList, meltAndNameDT)
```

This works but the use of the assign function and the altering of variables in the global environment seems to be generally thought of as bad practice.

My question is twofold - firstly is there a simple way of assigning in lapply the returned objects list to the corresponding objects of the input list, and would this be memory efficient?  And secondly is there a better, or more correct way of doing this than the second approach?

Thanks in advance for your thoughts, I'm fairly new to R and been struggling to get my head around this.

Comment: A best practice in R is to continue using list of many similar objects (as opposed to many separate objects flooding global environment) and never have functions modify global environment (for debugging, maintainability, reproducibilty, and other reasons).